# Did Jewish ritual circumcision become a more invasive procedure in 140 CE?

Tags: jews, circumcision

One can envision two different methods to circumcize a
penis based on where the cut is placed. The first method involves
placing the cut *after* the glans and the second placing it *before*
the glans. The first method would expose the urethra, but leave most
of the glans covered, while the second method would leave the glans
completely exposed. For the circumsised, these two procedures are
much different. The image below demonstrates the difference:

[image]

What I think is a myth goes as follows:

Jews used to practice the first method, but as many male Jews
practiced epispasm, the Rabbinate (?) in 140 CE decreed that the
second method should be used instead. Epispasm means restoring the
function of the foreskin by stretching it by tying weights to
it. *Some* male Jews practiced epispasm in antiquity but it is very
unclear how widespread the practice was. The Rabbis objected to
epispasm and therefore imposed the second circumcision method,
according to the claim.

This claim can easily be found on anti-circumcision sites. One source
for the claim is Jim Bigelow's book *The Joy of Uncircumcising!* p.8:

> I have met very few Jews and even fewer Christians who know that the
> style of circumcision which is practiced both by Jews and the
> medical profession today bears little resemblance to the
> circumcision rite in biblical times. Almost no modern-day Christians
> know that the rabbis radicalized the circumcision procedure in
> approximately 140 A.D. Before that time it was a rather simple,
> symbolic procedure, quite different from the current practice which
> denudes and permanently alters the nature of the glans. Most
> Christians assume that God told Abraham to carry out a procedure
> something like that which a modern doctor or rabbi calls
> circumcision. It follows, therefore, that what they have the doctor
> do to their son is a circumcision like God told Abraham to do some
> 4,000 years ago. It isn’t!

Bigelow's source for the claim is Kaufmann Kohler's entry
"Circumcision" in *The Jewish Encyclopedia* from 1964 p. 93, which I
can't find online. The same claim can be found in
*[Circumcision: then and now](http://www.cirp.org/library/history/peron2/)*
by James E. Peron p. 41-42:

> The original Biblical circumcision of Abraham's time was a
> relatively minor ritual circumcision procedure in which only the
> redundant end of the foreskin extending beyond the tip of the glans
> was removed. [...] No other feature was added to the religious
> ritual until about 140 AD when a second step to the ritual
> circumcision procedure was introduced. [...] Periah: The laying bare
> of the glans After performing "milah", the cutting back of the end
> of the infant's foreskin, a second step, periah was then
> performed. Periah consists of tearing and stripping back the
> remaining inner mucosal lining of the foreskin from the glans and
> then, by use of a sharp finger nail or implement, removing all of
> the inner mucosal tissue, including the excising and removal of the
> frenulum from the underside of the glans.
> The objective was to
> insure that no part of the remaining penile skin
> would rest against
> the glans corona.

Comment: The title and the body of the question do not match.  The title asks whether the practice changed, which is on-topic for this site, but the body asks how the myth (presupposing it is a myth) originated, which is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not familiar with either method. "In the most common procedure, the foreskin is opened, adhesions are removed, and the foreskin is separated from the glans" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcision). Both the glans and the urethra are undamaged in a perfect (allegedly modern?) circumcision. Something the first quote seems to recognize.

Comment: @jwodder I removed the reference to that. Still, if someone answers the question they should, of course, providence evidence and not just answer "Yes it is true"/"No it is false".

Comment: Oh, I see now from the pictures. Well, that they used to do it by pulling the foreskin and and nipping the end is more or less accepted, I believe, but it was a simple matter of having the right tools and anatomical knowledge (ancient fathers often performed the ritual, rather than a "specialist"). But that "you must remove *all* of the foreskin" was handed down from an authority is certainly a very interesting question. With that said, you might get better answers on https://judaism.stackexchange.com/, https://history.stackexchange.com/, or even https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For Kaufmann Kohler's entry "Circumcision" in The Jewish Encyclopedia try (from 1906) try http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4391-circumcision#anchor4 and in particular the third paragraph of that section.  It is also mentioned and referenced in the third paragraph of the Wikipedia article on [Brit milah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_milah)

Comment: We have a site dedicated to Judaism [judaism.se]. You might consider asking there.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. Anyway. @Henry, I checked the sources given in the wiki article and they are either dead ends - the author doesn't tell where they got their information from - or they link back to Kohler's entry in The Jewish Encyclopedia. Not saying that the ritual can't have changed, but if it did, how come it didn't cause massive theological debates and centuries-long schisms?

Comment: No time for this, but entirely true, largely invented by P-src, proc getting stronger after BarKochba, except such 'desires' by leaders are older (cf Jub15), src ISBN 9781589834095,  ISBN 1584653078. Despite assumed 'Egyptian heritage', current 'tradition' was emerging late, *against* mainly Greeks, Romans, Christians (also cf Gal)…

Answer (score 4):

I have consulted a source I missed when I asked my question
and now feel I can answer it. There is not enough evidence to conclude
that a new form of Jewish ritual circumcision (Periah) was introduced
in the second century. In fact, the opposite seem to be true; in 140
CE, Periah was well-established practice.

In [Infant Male Circumcision: A Catholic Theological and Bioethical
Analysis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6027118/),
David Albert Jones writes:

> It is attested from multiple sources that during the period between
> the Maccabean revolt (167 BC) and the Bar Kokba revolt (135 AD) some
> Jews sought to disguise or reverse their circumcision, some omitted
> to circumcise, and some practiced circumcision that did not involve
> removing the complete foreskin. It seems reasonable to conclude that
> this context explains the rabbinic insistence in the second century
> AD that periah must henceforth be regarded as a necessary element of
> Jewish circumcision. However, even if scholars are correct in
> arguing that this element only became a requirement for Jewish
> circumcision at this time, this would not demonstrate that this form
> of the ritual was only instituted at that time. Furthermore, even if
> it is granted, for the sake of argument, that this form of the
> ritual was only instituted in reaction to Hellenization, this would
> suggest an earlier date, around the time of the Maccabean
> revolt. Recent scholarship has discovered evidence of the practice
> of periah precisely in this context. In the book of Jubilees (from
> the second century BC) God warns Abraham about a future generation
> who “will not circumcise their sons in accord with this entire law
> because they will leave some of the flesh of their circumcision when
> they circumcise their sons” (Jubilees 15:33, emphasis
> added). Concerning this passage, Thiessen states that “most
> interpreters see here a reference to the practice of periah, in
> which the entirety of the foreskin is removed” (Thiessen 2014,
> 385). Thiessen here cites Rubin (2003), but Rubin reserves judgment
> on this point, referring to the differences in the translations of
> Charles and VanderKam and speculating that these may reflect
> underlying textual differences. However, VanderKam confirmed to me
> in personal communication that the critical texts constructed by
> Charles (in 1895) and his own (in 1989) do not differ on this
> passage, and the difference is due to a mistake in translation by
> Charles. The Jewish Encyclopedia of 1906 would not have had access
> to an accurate translation of this passage from the book of
> Jubilees.
>
> There seems every reason, therefore, to believe that periah was
> practiced by at least some Jews in the second century BC and that
> during this period omitting the periah was associated with Hellenism
> and was regarded by its opponents, whether correctly or incorrectly,
> as an innovation.

The argument is that a passage in the [Book of
Jubilees](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Book-of-Jubilees) defines a
proper circumcision as Periah and dissuades Jews from leaving foreskin
on the penis. Thus Periah was not invented in the second century CE.

My take is that among Jews in the Greco-Roman world, practice was not
uniform. It is entirely possible that Milah and Periah coexisted. For
example, the first century Roman writer Aulus Cornelius Celsus
described a device called pondus Judaeus which Jewish men would attach
to their penis to stretch their foreskin so that it would cover the
glans. This implies that Periah wasn't always practiced since then
there would be no leftover skin to use for stretching. Perhaps some
families would opt for Milah if previous babies died after
being circumcised.